# How to use scale_x_date properly

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am a new user in R and I hope you can help me.

```
setwd("C:/Users/USER/Desktop/Jorge")
agua <- read_excel("agua.xlsx")
pbi <- read_excel("PBIagro.xlsx")
str(agua); 
names(agua)[2] <- "Variación";
agua[,1] <- as.Date(agua$Trimestre)

lagpbi <- lag(pbi$PBIAgropecuario, k=1)
pbi[,3]<- lagpbi; pbi <- pbi[-c(1),]; 
names(pbi)[3] <- "PBIlag"

growth <- ((pbi$PBIAgropecuario-pbi$PBIlag)/pbi$PBIlag)*100
Anual_growth <- data.frame(growth); Anual_growth[,2] <- pbi$Año; names(Anual_growth)[2] <- "Año"


# Plot
Agro <- ggplot(Anual_growth, aes(x=Año, y=growth)) +
  geom_line(color="steelblue") + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(Anual_growth$growth, 1)),
            vjust = "inward", hjust = "inward", size=2.5, show.legend = FALSE) +
  xlab("") +
  theme_ipsum() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1)) +
  ylim(-9.9,13.4) + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_blank(), plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,0.5,1),"cm"),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_text(face = "bold", size=8, 
        angle=1,hjust=0.95,vjust=0.2),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank())+
        scale_x_continuous("Año", labels = as.character(Anual_growth$Año), breaks = Anual_growth$Año)

print(Agro)
```

[image]

The problem is that it shows all the years, but I only want pair years (in X-axis) or years with step equal to 2. 
I hope you can really help me.
Thank you.
Notice that the X-axis variable is a numeric string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want pair years and because your x-axis variable is numeric, you can specify in `scale_x_continous` that `breaks` argument should take only `even` numbers.

Here how you can do it using this small example:

```r
year = 1998:2020
value = rnorm(23,mean = 3)
df = data.frame(year,value)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = value))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = year[year %%2 ==0])
```

[image]

Reciprocally, if you want odd years, you just have to specify `scale_x_continuous(breaks = year[year %%2 != 0])`

So, in your code, you should write:

```r
scale_x_continuous(breaks = Anual_growth$Año[Anual_growth$Año %%2 ==0])
```

Does it answer your question ?

Answer (score 6):

You can add something like 
`scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 years", date_labels = "%Y")` to your ggplot.

This is how it looks with my data, since you haven't posted yours. I am plotting a type `date` on x axis.

1.

```
ggplot(mydata) +
 aes(x = date, y = number, color = somevar) +
 geom_line()
```

[image]

2. ```
   ggplot(mydata) +
     aes(x = date, y = number, color = somevar) +
     geom_line() +
   scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%Y")
   ```

[image]

3.

```
ggplot(mydata) +
  aes(x = date, y = number, color = somevar) +
  geom_line() +
scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 years", date_labels = "%Y")
```

[image]